# Google Tag Manager wont post to collect url unless in preview mode

Tags: google-tag-manager

When running javascript

```
dataLayer.push({'event': 'hiThere'});
```

in my website, no network activity happens.  Whats expected is that it posts to the 'collect' url.

When I am in preview mode, this works.  Why?  What do I need to do to get the dataLayer.push function to work in normal operation.

Thanks

Comment: Chances are that you have forgotten to publish the container, but all in all this is too little information - datalayer pushes do not send anything anywhere, the tags that you have configured do. How does your trigger look like, how does your tag look like (and again, did you remember to publish via the submit-button in the upper right)?

Comment: I think its because I haven't published.  The account manager gave me a sub account and will publish at a future date so I will keep this thread posted.